# Magento 1 : emoji not display

Tags: magento-1.9

I'll create one custom table in Magento 1 to store the data.

I want to store emoji in my custom table and display it in the frontend
I'll store data something like  `'Hdhdhdhhzhzhzz'`
but it displays like `Hdhdhdh????????????????hzhzhz`

How to solve this?

Comment: May I know your table structure?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ji01p4

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ji01rl

Answer (score 1):

Change your table's fields `COLLATE` where you are saving emoji From CURRENT to `COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin'`.

Comment: Still in frontend it show as ?????

Comment: May I know your code for fetch that data?